# String type not allowed (at textColor with value 'black'): Android Studios

Tags: android

[image]

I am fairly new to using android studios.
 the below error cropped up while trying to adjust the color

Comment: show your xml layout

Comment: you didn't provide your code (the **text**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

or this

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#ff00"/>
```

or this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@android:color/black` or provide a hexadecimal color code value

Comment: why a down vote?

Comment: Tnks that fixed it

Comment: Please upvote the answer

Comment: I did !. The website appears to be gitching